# SQL Performance difference when doing Join on Subselect of Table instead of whole table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is meant as a general question and not for specific my own database.

Here is a simple example of the database. For simplicity I spare the datatypes because they aren't of interest.

Table **Animals**:

```
ID, Name, Specie, OwnerID
```

Table **Owner**:

```
ID, Name, Street, City, Country
```

Now would there be a difference in the performance if I do

```
SELECT o.Name
FROM [Animals] a
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, Name FROM [Owner]) o ON o.ID = a.OwnerID
```

instead of simply

```
SELECT o.Name
FROM [Animals] a
INNER JOIN [Owner] o ON o.ID = a.OwnerID
```

So, I was thinking there could be an increased performance because I don't go on the whole table. 
But also I think it could be that SQL is smart enough to internally do almost the same.

I tried to measure it in a database of my own, but I couldn't measure a difference big enough to be sure it isn't just floor noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether there's a performance difference depends on the query plans SQL server is using, which in turn depends on specific table structure including indices, foreign key constraints, and data types. This can also change depending on how much data you have and how it's distributed.

For the two queries you posted, assuming [this relatively-simple table structure and data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c47f/1/0), both queries have the execution plan shown below, meaning SQL Server followed this same algorithm for both.

[image: Sample execution plan]

You can get trees like this using Sql Server Management Studio to run these queries. Hunt for a toolbar button called "Include Actual Execution Plan," enable it, and then run them again. In addition to the usual 'Results' and 'Messages' tab, you'll get an 'Execution Plan' tab, showing this visual representation of the algorithm SQL Server has chosen. Comparing the two plans will tell you whether SQL is behaving the same way for the two queries.

For more details on the plans and what they mean, have a look at [StackOverflow: how to read a execution plan in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-a-execution-plan-in-sql-server).

Comment: Thank you very much i dont know why i didnt get the idea to take a look at the execution plan... 
So i have done this in my own specific example and can confirm that there is no difference at all.